# Can't install TTFQuery via pip install

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to use `TTFQuery` module but when i write the command `pip3 install TTFQuery` it returns the following error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: 'c:\users\pranon rahman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\PRANON~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2hpgfba\\TTFQuery\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PRANON~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z2hpgfba\\TTFQuery\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);
        code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\PRANON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2u2rs2sz'
         cwd: C:\Users\PRANON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z2hpgfba\TTFQuery\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\PRANON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z2hpgfba\TTFQuery\setup.py", line 11
        except ImportError, err:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 5):

[TTFQuery 1.0.5](https://pypi.org/project/TTFQuery/1.0.5/), last released in 2012. The code is obviously only for Python 2.

There is a beta release [2.0.0b1](https://pypi.org/project/TTFQuery/2.0.0b1/) from 2018. Try

```
pip install TTFQuery==2.0.0b1
```